# wireless network interference

Tags: wireless-networking

My wireless connection to my Samsung tv is set up via a Linksys E2500 coupled with a Netgear extender. Often my connection to the internet on my smart hub drops with a message saying that connnection was lost due to network interference.

I then have to reset both routers to regain internet connection...only to have it bounced soon after watching tv again.

What might be causing this and how can I correct the problem?

Comment: Well, it says you have interference from somewhere. What have you done to mitigate this? Are you using 2.4GHz, the most over-subscribed range in living memory, or the newer 5GHz? Have you tried selecting a static wireless channel, or are you using automatic channel selection?

Answer (score 1):

What might be causing this issue?

- A neighboring router on the same WiFi channel.
- A Microwave Oven.
- A 2.4ghz cordless phone (the 900mhz ones are outdated now).
- A Bluetooth device.
- The Netgear Extender broadcasting on the same WiFi Channel (you should always use channels that are 5 apart.. 1 and 6, 2 and 7, 3 and 8, etc)

Read up on [Electromagnetic Interference at 2.4ghz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz).

What can you do about it?  All depends on what is causing it.  Might be as simple as changing channels on the router/netgear extender.  Might need to move the router closer and not use the extender.

Comment: Had several neighbors on the same channel as me (live on the corner).  Changing channels worked for me.  Usually the simplest option.  Try this first.